# Can RedGate Data Compare Use Joins?

Tags: sql-server, redgate

Using Redgate SQL Data Compare 9.

This is a simplified example of what I want to do.  I have the following tables:

```
Product (ProductId, ProductName)         
ProductDetail (ProductDetailId, ProductId, OtherField)
```

Id columns in both tables are primary keys and auto-increment (identity).  Product has a unique constraint on ProductName. I have a production system and a test system, and would like to use Data Compare to sync the ProductDetail tables of the two systems.

The problem is that the two systems' id columns are not synchronized.  A product called "Bananas" could have an Id of 1000 in production and an Id of 6 in test.

What I would like to do is compare using a join--so instead of using a key made up of only columns in the ProductDetail table, I could compare based on a combination of fields using both the Product and ProductDetail tables.

I don't see any way of having more than one table participate in a comparison in the Data Compare UI.  Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can span multiple tables in building a custom comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a query with the desired join condition, create a table with the results on each db and use rg to compare those tables

Comment: I'd recommend creating a View to do this as SQL Data Compare can also compare views (although this needs to be enabled in the options)